# El resultado de la expresión siempre es 'true' porque un valor del tipo 'decimal' nunca es igual a 'NULL' de tipo 'decimal?' c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy tratando mediante `Entity Framework` obtener la sumatoria de lo realizado por una persona  Y visualizarlo en un label pero al momento de realizar la validación me arroja el mensaje de la pregunta `El resultado de la expresión siempre es 'true' porque un valor del tipo 'decimal' nunca es igual a 'NULL' de tipo 'decimal?'`

```
select SUM(PRE_VAL_TOT) 
from TBL_PRESUPUESTO 
where PRE_EST_REA='R' AND 
PRE_ELA_PRE='2023-03-23' AND
PRE_COD_ODON='0003'
```

Esto realizo en el sql y me arroja sin problema el resultado.

Ahora al pasarlo a c#

```
public void Calcular_Gananacia_Presupuesto(string Fec_Ela, string Cod_Odon, Label lblRes, string Nombre)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var odontologo = db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(x => x.PRE_EST_REA == "R" && x.PRE_ELA_PRE == Fec_Ela && x.PRE_COD_ODON == Cod_Odon).Select(x => x.PRE_VAL_TOT).Sum();
                if (odontologo != null)
                {
                    lblRes.Text = "EL DR: " + Nombre + "TUVO UN INGRESO DE " + AQUI NECESITO EL RESULTADO DE LA SUMATORIA ;
                }
               
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Adjunto la clase TBL_PRESUPUESTO.

```
 public partial class TBL_PRESUPUESTO
{
    public int PRE_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRE_COD { get; set; }
    public string PRE_COD_PAC { get; set; }
    public string PRE_NOM_PAC { get; set; }
    public string PRE_COD_ODON { get; set; }
    public string PRE_NOM_ODON { get; set; }
    public string PRE_RUT { get; set; }
    public string PRE_DEN_PAC { get; set; }
    public string PRE_PIE_DEN { get; set; }
    public string PRE_TRA_PAC { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_PRE { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_POR { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_DES { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_SUB { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_POR_DSC_SUB { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_TOT_DSC_SUB { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_POR_TAR_SUB { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_TOT_TAR_SUB { get; set; }
    public decimal PRE_VAL_TOT { get; set; }
    public string PRE_ELA_PRE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PRE_ELA_ACT { get; set; }
    public string PRE_EST_ELI { get; set; }
    public string PRE_EST_REA { get; set; }
}
```

Que estoy realizando de manera errónea, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Agrega la clase `TBL_PRESUPUESTO`

Comment: @Yussef agregue la informacion de la tabla.

Comment: Pero eso es un error o una advertencia, pq son cosas bien diferentes?

Comment: Aplica tu consulta linq sin el operador Sum y dime que sucede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las variables de tipo valor (como decimal, int, bool...) son non-nullable es decir nunca serán igual a null por su naturaleza, por citar un ejemplo y sin entrar en mucho detalle, piensa en un tipo bool que puede ser false o true y listo, en c# un bool no puede ser null, así como un decimal tampoco puede ser null, el método Sum() te regresa un decimal que no puede ser null, ahora bien existen los [nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) que sería la forma de hacer nullable un dato de tipo valor, en nuestro ejemplo ahora bool "puede ser" false, true y null, para especificar que queremos usar un nullable type solo hay que agregar el signo de interrogación al crear nuestra variable, ejemplo

```
bool valor;// este es un non-nullable, solo puede ser true or false
bool? valorNullable;//ahora es un nullable type, puede ser true, false or null
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso Sum() está diseñado para regresar un decimal(non-nullable), por eso el compilador desde antes de ejecutar el programa te dice que no puedes comparar el valor con un null, en tu query Sum() nunca regresará un null, de hecho si no encuentra valores lo más probable es que te genere un excepción.

Una opción es usar `DefaultIfEmpty()` en tu consulta

```
 var odontologo = db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO
   .Where(x => x.PRE_EST_REA == "R" && x.PRE_ELA_PRE == Fec_Ela && x.PRE_COD_ODON == Cod_Odon)
   .Select(x => x.PRE_VAL_TOT)
   .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
   .Sum();
    
if (odontologo > 0)
    lblRes.Text = "EL DR: " + Nombre + "TUVO UN INGRESO DE " + odontologo ;
```

Comment: al aplicar tu código siempre me visualiza 0

Comment: Es probable que tu consulta no esté regresando ningún valor y por eso todo queda en 0, prueba db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO
   .Where(x => x.PRE_EST_REA == "R" && x.PRE_ELA_PRE == Fec_Ela && x.PRE_COD_ODON == Cod_Odon)
   .Select(x => x.PRE_VAL_TOT).ToList() ahí si podrás consultar si odontlogo == null, si es null entonces tu consulta no está encontrando ningún dato

Comment: Efectivamente tu consulta estaba correcta , el problema reside en que al momento de enviar a evaluar la fecha el formato esta guardado como un varchar tipo yyyy-mm-dd y yo lo enviaba dd/mm/yyyy con lo cual jamás iba a coincidir o arrojar valor alguno, de antemano agradezco tu ayuda un abrazo campeón